# Can we say "she stole the spotlight" even though someone else was already in the spotlight before?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

When we say "**A stole the toy**", it implies the toy belonged to someone else before.

Similarly, when we say "**A stole the spotlight**", does it imply the spotlight belonged to someone else before?

**Situation 1**, say, Mary was standing in front of a lot of students bragging about her success when suddenly, Jen, out of nowhere, sang loudly to get attention from the students. We can say "**Jen stole the spotlight**".

**Situation 2**, all the students were eating in a cafeteria when  Jen, out of nowhere, sang loudly to get attention from the students. Do we say "**Jen stole the spotlight**"?

Comment: To [*steal the spotlight*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stole+the+spotlight%2Cstole+the+limelight&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) looks a bit odd to me as a Brit (it's almost exclusively American). Brits [*steal the **limelight.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stole+the+spotlight%2Cstole+the+limelight&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10) They're ***figurative*** usages that you can look up in any dictionary - nothing to do with literal theft of spotlights or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

*steal the spotlight*
has similar meaning as *steal the limelight*, which is an idiom meaning

> to get more **attention** than anyone or anything else in a situation.

The former idiom is more common in AmE; and the latter, BrE, as @FumbleFingers commented.
Though the definition and other similar ones do not state whether the **attention** has to first belong to someone else, *steal* suggests that the idioms work better in *Situation 1* than in *Situation 2*, which likely did not and would not even have any limelight otherwise.